# Hide option in flag

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

Can I somehow hide any option using standard library flag? This means flag would work, but --help would not print this option.

And it would be more nice to print --option instead of -option in help. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard pkg does not support this thing you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can use: https://godoc.org/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [cli](https://github.com/urfave/cli) package instead.